# 3D Graphing Software - Solid of Revolution

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, 3d, math-software, solid-of-revolution

I'm taking AP Calc with AoPS, and we're learning how to find the volumes of some 3D solids using integration methods. In particular, we're learning about shapes called solids of revolution, which are formed by rotating the area under a 2D curve about the $x$-axis. For example:

[image: Solid of revolution]

Some solids of revolution are also formed by rotating the area under a 2D curve about the $y$-axis:

[image]

Is there any good software that I can use to visualize such solids formed from an arbitrary curve? Preferably even solids formed from an intersection of two such curves. GeoGebra, Math3D, and Manim all seem to be good, but I don't really see an easy option to graph such solids of revolution. I have to use parametric surfaces or something similar, which is difficult for me to do since I haven't really learnt about those. I understand that parametric surfaces give a 3D vector in terms of $u$ and $v$, but I can't figure out how to convert solids of revolution to a parametric surface. Perhaps a tip for that? Finding a good 3D graphing software would generally be useful though, since I'll probably need it anyways for future courses. GeoGebra seems to have a very poor documentation, and Manim might be too complicated for simple graphs. I just found Math3D, so I haven't really had a chance to uncover its pros and cons. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any particular curve to plot in mind or just looking for a 3D software?

Comment: I suggest you trying Maple! It is very student friendly.

Comment: WolframAlpha has okay support for this sort of thing. If the bounded region that defines the solid is sufficiently unambiguous, you can get a pretty [decent results](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=revolve+region+bounded+by+y+%3D+x%2C+y+%3D+0%2C+and+x+%3D+1+about+x%3D2). They even include parametric equations for the surface in most cases which could help you get acquainted with them. Having a good grasp on cylindrical coordinates is a must to understand where the equations are coming from. But be warned, this feature has been quite buggy in my experience, so I'd tread carefully.

Comment: GeoGebra is probably still your best bet. Just google plotting solids of revolution using GeoGebra or search their online archive https://www.geogebra.org/materials for solids of revolution.

Comment: @Mikasa I'm mainly looking for a generic 3D software, but it is for the purpose of solving problems. I can give you some example problems, but I want to be able to use the same software for all similar problems. Here's an example problem:

Find the volume of the solid formed by rotating the region bound by the curves $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ about the $x$-axis.

Comment: @user170231 It's super cool how they can graph my problem just by describing it in words! (see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=plot+the+solid+formed+by+rotating+the+area+bound+by+the+functions+x%5E2+and+%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D+about+the+x+axis)) The power of AI  Unfortunately, though, the graph doesn't look very clear to me, and since I can't move it around, I'm not able visualize the solid very well. Since that was the point of graphing the solid, I don't think this will work well for my use case. I'll definitely try it out for different use cases though!

Comment: @Mikasa I can't seem to find Maple. Could you please share a link?

Comment: Maple is commercial software

Comment: @Paul oh... GeoGebra is working well now, and I was able to find some easy methods to graph solids of revolution. I'll see if I can turn this into an answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should use math3d.org. [Demo](https://www.math3d.org/ZWxAvgcR)

Comment: @TymaGaidash can you show me a demo for [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=plot+the+solid+formed+by+rotating+the+area+bound+by+the+functions+x%5E2+and+%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D+about+the+x+axis) problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoGebra and WolframAlpha (thanks @user170231!) seem to work well for me right now. Here's a quick overview of how solids of revolution can be graphed using either software:

## WolframAlpha

Explain the figure in as precise a language as possible. For example, *"The solid formed by rotating the area bound by the functions $x^2$ and $\sqrt{x}$ about the x axis"*. Type this into the text field at [WolframAlpha](https://wolframalpha.com). You should get a graph!

[image: WolframAlpha prompt]

[image: WolframAlpha graph]

There is one downside to this though. The graph can't be moved or rotated, which may not allow for a good intuition all the time. Since this is powered by AI, it's not guaranteed to work all the time either. GeoGebra offers a more comprehensive graphing platform. GeoGebra's downside, however, is that it's impossible (or really difficult) to graph rotations like this. Instead, only the rotations of curves can be sketched, which means that a problem such as the one above must be split into two. Instead of graphing the rotation of the area between the functions $x^2$ and $\sqrt{x}$, we must graph the rotations of both the functions separately and mentally imagine subtracting the volume of one from the other.

## GeoGebra

Go to the [GeoGebra 3D Calculator](https://www.geogebra.org/3d). I will demonstrate the graphing functionality with the same example that was used above. Note that $0\leq x\leq 1$ should be replaced with the intersections of both the functions chosen, and the functions themselves ($x^2$ and $\sqrt{x}$) must be replaced.

- f(x)=If(0<=x<=1,x^2)
- g(x)=If(0<=x<=1,sqrt(x))
- a=Surface(f,360deg)
- b=Surface(g,360deg)

[image: GeoGebra commands]

$a$ and $b$ can be switched on or off and colors changed to give a better intuition of the solid.

[image: GeoGebra graph]

And of course, the graph can be moved around and rotated to give a better sense of what the solid really looks like! I found these tools really helpful for visualizing solids of revolution, thus helping me solve problems involving these better. They also helped me understand the intuition behind the formulas for finding the volume of such solids. I hope this was helpful for you too!

Comment: You can also put in a slider $\theta$ taking values from $0^0$ to $360^0$ and plot Surface(f, $\theta$, xAxis). As you change $\theta$ you will see the surface generated from the rotation.

Comment: I know that, but that isn't very useful for me. Maybe it's useful for others, so thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

[Asymptote](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Ecstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf) is free and can produce high-quality plots, possibly containing some LaTeX.

```
settings.outformat = "png";
settings.render = 4;
import three;
size(5cm, 0);
path s = (0, 0){up} .. (1, 1) .. (2, sqrt(2));
path3 p3 = path3(s);
surface mysolid = surface(p3, c = O, axis = X, n = 64);
draw(mysolid, red);
```

[image]

---

## EDIT

```
settings.outformat = "png";
settings.render = 4;
import three;
size(5cm, 0);
currentprojection = orthographic(3, 4, 2);
currentlight = light(
    diffuse = new pen[] {cyan, orange}, 
    specular = new pen[] {black, white}, 
    position = new triple[] {-Y+Z, X+Y}
);
path s1 = (0, 0){up} .. (0.5, sqrt(0.5)) .. (1, 1);
path s2 = (1, 1){down} .. (0.5, 0.5**2) .. (0, 0);
path3 p3 = path3(s1 .. s2);
surface mysolid = surface(p3, c = O, axis = X, n = 64);
draw(mysolid, green);
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand how to plot 3D figures using functions - specifically, solids of revolution. There doesn't seem to be much good documentation for Asymptote, that's why I usually avoid it. Would it be possible for you to show an example in Asymptote for the solid of revolution formed by rotating the area bound by the functions $x^2$ and $\sqrt{x}$ about the $x$-axis? Thanks!

Comment: @Zo-Bro-23 See my edit.

Comment: Oh wow thanks! I find GeoGebra and WolframAlpha to be easier to use and understand though. I get that Asymptote has a lot of potential, however, so I may decide to switch in the future. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Strategy 1**

Math3d.org [**plots**](https://www.math3d.org/5HQvAXdNd) your shape with this input into a parametric surface:

$[v,v^2\cos(u),v^2\sin(u)],u\in[-\pi,\pi],v\in[0,1]$

and

$$[v,v^\frac12\cos(u),v^\frac12\sin(u)],u\in[-\pi,\pi],v\in[0,1]$$

[image]

Also, one sees a pattern for revolving $f(x)$ about the $x$ axis:

$$[v,f(v)\cos(u),f(v)\sin(u)]$$

Where $v$ adjusts the domain and $u$ adjusts the revolution angle, like how $u\in[0,\pi]$ revolves $f(x)$ by $180^\circ$ . You can rotate the figure, zoom in, and adjust “Axes & Camera”

**Strategy 2**

There is another way too with the  explicit/implicit surface feature shown [here](https://www.math3d.org/aXuvrsfZ2). To revolve $f(x)$ about the $x$ axis, you type

$$x=f\left((y^2+z^2)^\frac12\right)$$

Although the restrictions on $x,y,z$ cannot make circles:

[image]

**Conclusion**

You can plot much more than surfaces of revolution too. Clearly, strategy 1 will be best.